How to change border color of focused window
I am working on a gnome extension. I am trying to put border around windows.
_add_orange_border_to_window = function (win) {
    if (!win) return;

    let actor = win.get_compositor_private().get_parent();
    if (!actor) return;

    if (!borders[win]) {
        borders[win] = new St.Bin({
            style_class: 'border'
        });
        actor.add_child(borders[win]);
    }

    const BORDERSIZE = 3;

    function redrawBorder() {
        let rect = win.get_frame_rect();
        borders[win].set_position(rect.x - BORDERSIZE, rect.y - BORDERSIZE);
        borders[win].set_size(rect.width + 2 * BORDERSIZE, rect.height + 2 * BORDERSIZE);
    }

    function restack(display){
        actor.get_children().forEach(
            (child) => {
                let sibling = Meta.get_window_group_for_display(display);
                sibling.set_child_above_sibling(actor, this);
            }
        )
    }

    redrawBorder();

    // Connect to the size-changed and position-changed signals
    signalHandlers[win] = {
        sizeChangedId: win.connect('size-changed', redrawBorder),
        positionChangedId: win.connect('position-changed', redrawBorder),
        restackHandlerID : Display.connect('restacked', restack),
        unmanagedId: win.connect('unmanaged', () => {
            actor.remove_child(borders[win]);
            win.disconnect(signalHandlers[win].sizeChangedId);
            win.disconnect(signalHandlers[win].positionChangedId);
            win.disconnect(signalHandlers[win].restackHandlerID);
            win.disconnect(signalHandlers[win].unmanagedId);
            delete borders[win];
            delete signalHandlers[win];
        })
    };
}

This code works. But there is an issue. When drawing multiple borders all the borders seems to be on top of all the windows.

I have checked Adding color to borders gnome windows. It says:

That’s because the borders aren’t actually windows. The compositor has
no idea where to put them in the stack, so ignores them.
You have to move them to the right layer yourself, and connect to the
global.display('restacked') signal to update them.

There is also a working code there.
But I could not figure out what to do. The given code is all i have managed so far and it is giving rectangles on top of all the windows.
What can I do?

Have you tried the code at the bottom of the post you linked to? The line global.window_group.set_child_above_sibling(window.border, child) in that code looks like it does what you want.

I created a text extension with that complete code. It has the same issue he mentioned. I understand that the solution is around global.window_group, but could not get it to work.

Hi Andy, The problem is solved. Please check https://github.com/blueray453/gnome-utils-by-blueray453/blob/main/markedWindowFunctions.js The code  at the bottom of the post was buggy (at least did not work for me). Anyways, I have another question, I my code, I need to call a function to markedWindowFunctions.js from windowFunctions.js. I am wondering if there is a standard for that in gnome extension.

There probably isn't a standard function, it seems like something GNOME Shell would do in a very specific way, so not well suited for a general function.

Alhamdulillah, The problem is solved.
let markedWindowsData = {};

_redraw_border = function (win, border) {
    let rect = win.get_frame_rect();
    border.set_position(rect.x, rect.y);
    border.set_size(rect.width, rect.height);
}

_mark_window(win) {
    if (!win) return;

    let actor = win.get_compositor_private();
    let actor_parent = actor.get_parent();

    let border = new St.Bin({
        style_class: 'border'
    });

    actor_parent.add_child(border);

    this._redraw_border(win, border);

    markedWindowsData[win] = {
        win_id: win.get_id(),
        border: border,
        sizeChangedId: win.connect('size-changed', () => this._redraw_border(win, border)),
        positionChangedId: win.connect('position-changed', () => this._redraw_border(win, border)),
        restackHandlerID: Display.connect('restacked', (display) => {
            let wg = Meta.get_window_group_for_display(display);
            wg.set_child_above_sibling(border, actor);
        }),
        unmanagedId: win.connect('unmanaged', () => {
            global.window_group.remove_child(border);
            win.disconnect(markedWindowsData[win].sizeChangedId);
            win.disconnect(markedWindowsData[win].positionChangedId);
            Display.disconnect(markedWindowsData[win].restackHandlerID);
            win.disconnect(markedWindowsData[win].unmanagedId);
            delete markedWindowsData[win];
        })
    };
}

For complete example, please check here.
